# Impact of placement of ObjectMapper object used with MixIn class on performance/functionality of Spring Boot application

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am in the beginning stages of developing a new Spring Boot application, and in it I have entities, repositories, and controllers. In some cases, I wanted to return only specific properties of objects in the returned JSON, so I used  `mixin` from Jackson in order to setup the json properties as per my requirements. Now, in a controller (annotated with `@RestController`) I have a method that returns a String (which is JSON), as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getbylang/{lang}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String getByQueryJsonIgnore(@PathVariable String lang) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(CountryDetail.class, CountryDetailMixIn.class);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(countryRepository.getCountriesByLanguageCode(lang));     
    }
```

In the code above, the `countryRepository.getCountriesByLanguageCode` method returns a `List<CountryDetail>`. My question is, is there a better performance or cleaner approach than having to create a `mapper` instance inside each controller method I want to deal with `mixin` or other JSON related behavior? Is it possible to create a global static `ObjectMapper` without breaking functionality (I am not knowledgeable enough about threading issues, Spring nuances, etc.)? Or is the performance impact negligible with the existing approach of creating a new `ObjectMapper` as needed within methods?

Thank you.

Comment: Creating the mapper per call will be fairly expensive, since it's highly reflective. Have you considered using a JSON projection as the straight return type from your controller method? Manual marshalling is a flaky approach in any case.

Comment: @chrylis no I have not considered JSON projection.Could you please point me towards an established reference on JSON projection?

Comment: @chrylis Also could you please provide more detail on what you mean when you say manual marshalling is flaky? I wasn't aware that is what I am doing, nor what it is.

Comment: To answer the second point (I think searching will get you as good as I could on projections): You can just return a `Country` object from your controller; there's no need to convert it into a `String`. Spring will automatically convert it into the appropriate format (and can even handle XML or JSON for you based on the `Accept` header).

Comment: @chrylis yes that is how I originally had it (with `List<CountryDetail>`) being returned from the controller. The reason I had to use `ObjectMapper` is because I didn't want all of the properties within each `CountryDetail` to be returned, so I had to use a mixin class to specify what properties to ignore (to preserve loose coupling instead of annotating within obect), which is why I had to use the `ObjectMapper` to return a String. is there a way in `ObjectMapper` that can return the object itself (i.e. an alternate to `writeValueAsString` that returns the object) and let Spring do the rest?

Comment: Try https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by comments, constructing a new `ObjectMapper` per call is VERY costly: possibly in order of 100x more time may be taken than if reusing mapper.

Note, however, that you should be able to reuse an instance without having to use mapper that Spring Boot itself uses. For example, you can just create a `static` member of the class: mapper instances are thread-safe as long as all configuration (including defining mix-ins) is done before first call to `readValue()` or `writeValue()`.

If you do need different mix-ins for different endpoints you may need to use more than one mapper instance, although probably not one per each endpoint (presumably some share mix-in settings, or have ones that do not overlap). This is still more efficient than throw-away instances, although will use more memory.

Comment: If I were to go with the `static` member approach, where would be a good location to declare and configure it? Would it be at the beginning of every controller declaration above all the methods, after which I could just use `mapper.someMapperMethod` within methods as needed? Or should it be somewhere else more global, so as to avoid declaring `static` `ObjectMapper`s in multiple controllers?

Comment: @ITWorker I would go with something more global, unless they must be configured differently. Using DI is not a bad idea if framework makes that easy.